# How to prevent PhoneGap device ready function to be executed twice

Tags: javascript, cordova, ripple

In my app, I call the function init() upon loading a script file in index.html. The following code should verify whether cordova has succesfully loaded (for modern phones but specifically also for older BlackBerries) and subsequently call the onDeviceReady function.

I adapted the code from "20 Recipes for Programming PhoneGap" by Jamie Munro, but it didn't work properly (intervalID was only locally available). A later figured out that the onDeviceReady function was called multiple times... I tried several ways to prevent it, but even the below example doesn't do the trick when running in the ripple emulator.

What am I missing?

```
var count = 0

function init() {

    // Add an event listener for deviceready
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Older versions of Blackberry < 5.0 don't support
    // PhoneGap's custom events, so instead we need to perform
    // an interval check every 500 milliseconds to see whether
    // PhoneGap is ready.  Once done, the interval will be
    // cleared and normal processing can begin.
    intervalID = window.setInterval(function() {
        if (window.cordova) {
            window.clearInterval(intervalID);
            onDeviceReady();
        }
    }, 1000);
}

function onDeviceReady() {

    if(count == 0) {
        count += 1;
        alert('The device is now ready');
    }

}
```

Comment: Is device ready being called multiple times on the device? Ripple misbehaves lot of times and fires most events twice.

Comment: It actually behaves well on a blackberry, so I suppose it's justa little ripple in chrome...

Comment: yes... always test on device simulator or on actual device

Answer (score 1):

Ripple seems to load the page once to capture the URL and then loads it again within an iframe to display it on the simulated phone. So two copies of everything get loaded but into different documents. Since I get two events for everything including button clicks, it seems that both copies of my code receive the same event. Or maybe Ripple duplicates it for the other one. But with the code being in different documents and different scopes, they don't seem to interfere with each other (at least they haven't for me YET). Perhaps someone else can give a better, more knowledgeable explanation of what I think I detect.